# How to repeat all rows in a table for all the groups in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How to repeat all rows in a table for all the groups in another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT d.*, dp.dept, u.users_created
FROM dbo.dates d
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT DISTINCT dept FROM dbo.users ) as dp
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT COUNT(*) users_created 
              FROM dbo.users u 
              WHERE u.dept = dp.dept
              AND u.created_at >= d.month_start 
              AND u.created_at < d.next_month_start
            ) as u
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a simple SELECT COUNT from specified dates?

```
SELECT month_start, next_month_start, sum(cnt) as users, dept FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN created_at<=next_month_start AND created_at>=month_start THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as cnt,
users.*, month_start, next_month_start FROM users
CROSS JOIN dates) as S1
GROUP BY dept, month_start, next_month_start ORDER BY dept DESC
```

Comment: I do not understand how to do that. Could you help to write a query that generate the result in my question?

Comment: Sorry, added query. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT D.id dates_id,D.month_start dates_start,D.next_month_start dates_next_month_start,count(U.id) user_created,U.dept 

 FROM dates D 
 LEFT JOIN users U ON concat(year(U.created_at) ,"-",month(U.created_at)) = concat(year(D.month_start) ,"-",month(D.month_start)) 

 GROUP BY concat(year(D.month_start) ,"-",month(D.month_start)) ,concat(year(D.next_month_start) ,"-",month(D.next_month_start)) ;
```

Following is the out put

```
id  month_start                 next_month_start             user_created   dept
7   February, 01 2016 00:00:00  March, 01 2016 00:00:00       0             (null)
6   March, 01 2016 00:00:00     April, 01 2016 00:00:00       2             sales
5   April, 01 2016 00:00:00     May, 01 2016 00:00:00         3             sales
4   May, 01 2016 00:00:00       June, 01 2016 00:00:00        0             (null)
3   June, 01 2016 00:00:00      July, 01 2016 00:00:00        2              hr
2   July, 01 2016 00:00:00      August, 01 2016 00:00:00      0             (null)
1   August, 01 2016 00:00:00    September, 01 2016 00:00:00   0             (null)
```

Comment: This is not the same as I required. Note that I need to repeat the whole `dates` table for every department in `users` table. See the ascii table in my question. That's what I want.

Comment: Also are you using SQL Server as the database? I got syntax error when trying to execute it. It seems "_" is not valid in SQL Server.

Comment: OK, that's MySQL 5.6 and not SQL Server. I have sql-server as one of my tags.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?

```
SELECT sum(cnt), month_start, next_month_start, dept
 FROM
 (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN created_at<=next_month_start AND created_at>=month_start THEN 1 ELSE 0 END cnt,
    users.*, month_start, next_month_start
   FROM users
   CROSS JOIN dates
 ) sbt
 GROUP BY month_start, next_month_start, dept
```